# How does Amagiri Ayato get the nickname Murakumo?

Tags: gakusen-toshi-asterisk

[This wiki](https://asterisk.fandom.com/wiki/Amagiri_Ayato) lists Murakumo as an alias for Amagiri, but doesn't list how he gets it. I don't think anyone was calling him that before his high-profile duel with Toudou Kirin, but a girl calls him by the name at the start of the following episode.

I think it makes sense to assume that he was given the nickname when he took the rank 1 spot, but I don't know why that particular nickname was chosen for him. The wiki translates it to "Gathering Clouds" but I'm unsure what this has to do with anything. Is the reason for this nickname explained somewhere in the series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ayato's nickname "Murakumo" was given by Claudia.**

This was revealed in the introduction of Ayato's first Phoenix Tournament match.

From the light novel *The Asterisk War*, Vol. 3, Ch. 2 - *The Phoenix*,

> *“The first two onstage are Ayato Amagiri, Seidoukan Academy’s number one,
>   and Julis-Alexia von Riessfeld, number five! Now, Amagiri only rose to the top a
>   few weeks ago in a duel against the former top-ranked student! He is a truly
>   brand-new star—so new, in fact, we still don’t have much data on him
>   ourselves! **Ah, although we did hear his nickname Murakumo came from
>   Seidoukan’s student council president, Miss Enfield, herself.**”*
>
> <sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

However, the reason for the nickname itself was not stated anywhere.